# constant error Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings with pom.xml

Tags: java, pom.xml, slf4j

This is somewhat of a broad and hard to define question..

It seems now, more than ever before im stuck with

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

Error.

It seems this will pop up just about every time i add dependency.

Is my maven broken? or is it normal to be manually excluding this binding from
like 30% of all dependencies?

It seems almost every dependency has some version of this and maven seem to just give up trying
to use right version.

i have

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and then

4 x

```
<exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

in different depedencies...

with parent as

```
<version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
```

And im also now reading my effective pom, for third time this week to exclude random loggers...
I dont recall ever having to manually exclude any other components from pom, but this just creeps up time after time.

Thank you